# run forked process continuously, kill after interval

Tags: bash, process, kill, subshell

i'm having a difficult time writing a bash script, hoping someone could help. basically i'm trying to run a number of processes at the same time and then kill them all after an interval.

so for example, if i want to run `my_long_running_task` 50 times and kill after 10 minutes this is what i came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
PIDS=()

(while :
do
  my_long_running_task;
  sleep 1
done ) &
PIDS+=($!)

...{repeat while loop 50 times or stick it in a for loop)...

sleep 600; # 10 minutes * 60 seconds
for p in "${PIDS[@]}"
do
  kill $p
done
```

i'm not a bash expert but that seems like it should work - fork all the processes adding their pids to an array. then at the end just sleep for a certain amount of time before iterating over the array and killing all the pids. and indeed this worked for my very simple poc:

```
#!/bin/bash
PIDS=()

(while :
  do
    echo '1'
    sleep 1;
  done) &
PIDS+=($!)

(while :
  do
    echo '2'
    sleep 1;
  done) &
PIDS+=($!)

(sleep 10; \
for p in "${PIDS[@]}"
do
  kill $p
done)
```

but when i do something more interesting than `echo` - like, in my case, running phantomjs, the processes don't get killed after the interval.

any thoughts? what am i missing?

Comment: When you run `phantomjs`, do you run it with `exec` or just as a normal process?  Does it make any difference if you do use `exec`? The thought behind the questions is that you kill the shell that runs the other process (which, in the case of `echo`, is the shell), but don't necessarily kill the children of the process.  Maybe you need to use something like `kill -TERM -- -$p` to send a signal to the process group, rather than just the process.  Also, consider whether a 'time out' command would make your life easier (`timeout` on Linux).

Comment: i didn't know about the `timeout` command - i ended up using that. jonathan, why don't you post this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wish is my command (at least, when your wish aligns sufficiently with my desires):

> - When you run `phantomjs`, do you run it with `exec` or just as a normal process?
> - Does it make any difference if you do use `exec`?
>
> The thought behind the questions is that you kill the shell that runs the other process (which, in the case of `echo`, is the shell), but that doesn't necessarily kill the children of the process. Maybe you need to use something like:
>
> ```
> kill -TERM -- -$p
> kill -- -$p
> ```
>
> to send a signal to the process group, rather than just the process.
>
> Also, consider whether a 'time out' command would make your life easier ([`timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) on Linux).